# Pushing to private NuGet repository from Linux with SSL

Tags: linux, ssl, nuget, .net-core, nexus

I am currently trying to deploy a NuGet package to our local Nexus server from a Linux build machine (dotnet core project)

However, the Nexus server is running on HTTPS with a company domain certificate which is not recognised by my build machine.

When I run `nuget push` I get the following error:

```
Pushing App.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/'...
  PUT https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/
An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/'. The request will now be retried.
Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
  The authentication or decryption has failed.
  Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
  PUT https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/
An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/'. The request will now be retried.
Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
  The authentication or decryption has failed.
  Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
  PUT https://v-nexus/repository/nuget/
Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
  The authentication or decryption has failed.
  Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
```

I have tried:

- Installing the server certificate globally (using update-ca-certificates)
- Installing the certificate using certmgr

Is there any other way that I have missed, or is this a known issue using NuGet in Linux. (I am using docker containers so don't want the solution to be "use windows"!) This is forming part of our automated build system so I am limited to Linux docker containers.

One of my colleges, running Windows is able to push the package without any issues, so I know it's not an issue with the server.

Comment: Have you tried `mozroots --import --sync`?

Comment: Also check the `ca-certificates` package. If you are using the latest .NET Core CLI (1.0.0-rc4), you can use `dotnet nuget push` instead. `nuget push` was a third-party implementation of NuGet, provided by Mono. `dotnet nuget push` official, created by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It turns out I was trying to use the domain controller's certificate, rather than the CA cert. duh! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I came across it looking for an answer to this issue.

The problem seems to be Nuget, under Mono, [is broken](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3329).

It's not really an answer but hopefully it helps somebody else.